# Agreggation with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Heya I know I maybe shouldnt write here about such an issue but I just cant wrap my head around this. I have mongodb collection, let's call it summary. In there I got following fields: id, subsummaryId, date, price. Subsummaries are in intervals of 1 minute. I want to write aggregationbuilder that would make a report from the existing subsummaries. Report would return average hourly price for each hour per subsummaryId for last 24h. I'm having an issue with aggregation by hour.

```
db.Report.aggregate([{ $match: { date: { $gt: 0, $lt: 20 }}}, {$group: { _id: "$subsummaryId", hour: {"$hour": "$date"}, price: {$avg: "$price" }}}])
```

I'm getting

> "unknown group operator '$hour'"

Cheers!

Comment: Please help I have no idea how to make it work :<

Comment: If you are asking about aggregation pipeline in general, remove everything doctrine-related to the question. If you are asking about doctrine, provide a working aggregation pipeline using mongo shell.

Comment: Oki, done! Removed the doctrine part :) Well I have no idea how to make the pipeline in general. I beg for help...

Comment: Please read the docs on aggregation pipeline and try the examples provided there.

Comment: Pssst... are you still there? I managed to write it almost whole but I'm having issue with groupping it by hour. I did edit question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both id and hour need to be part of the bucket. Try:

```
  db.Report.aggregate([{ $match: { date: { $gt: 0, $lt: 20 }}},
 {$group: { _id: {subsummary: "$subsummaryId", hour: {"$hour": "$date"}}, price: {$avg: "$price" }}}])
```

If this doesn't work, add some sample data to the question.

If your date field contains a timestamp, `$lt: 20` doesn't look to me like it's going to do what you want.